# Rename Images with php and database

Tags: php, mysql, image, rename

Sorry, I did not know how to give it a better name and that´s my first thread here.

The problem I have is... I have a bunch of images that have filenames all in this syntax:

> ABC_1234-sometext.jpg

Just renaming it in php would not be a big deal but what I want is, I want to get the

> 1234

which is unique for each image (let´s call it products_ean) and do a SELECT query in my database which gives me back a different ID poducts_id) for each image which is also unique.

So what I want is to get

ABC_1234-sometext.jpg

into

56789.jpg

Where as the numbers are related by the database. Does that make sense?
I hope somebody could push me in the right direction.

This would be the query that result in the wanted image filename:

```
SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE products_ean = '.$img_name_strg.'
```

Comment: Ahh ok sorry. I was not really aware about that. But anyway it is tricky for me to give a MCRE here. Because the query itself is not the problem Ones I have filtered the numbers from the current filenames that is doable. Also the renaming should be easy. It is just the idea of how to stich the different parts together. Reading filename, Getting part of the name putting this in the query, which results in the new ID and then renaming the file. So what I need is more the outer construction of it all.

Comment: Suffice to say I disagree.

Comment: These files, are they already on your server or are you wanting to do this as part of an upload process

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can he do an update query in select query ?

Comment: filter functions can help you If you only want to get a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this now. It works. But I am not sure if this will work if I have to rename a thousand images? I guess to have the query in the foreach is not a nice way to go?

```
$dir = '/original_file_directory';
$destination = '/destination_directory/';

$files = glob($dir.'/*'); //get all images


foreach($files as $file){
    if(is_file($file)){

        $ean = substr(basename($file), 8, 5);

        $image_query = xtc_db_query("SELECT products_id FROM products WHERE 
        products_manufacturers_model = ".$ean."");
        $image_id = xtc_db_fetch_array($image_query);
        $image_id = $image_id['products_id'];


if($image_id != '')
       copy($file,$destination.$image_id.'.jpg');
    }
}
```

And what if I have files that would give me identical $ean and I would have to add ..._0.jpg and ..._1.jpg for those doubles?

Comment: I just tried it and even with around 2000 images it was working fine. This is a script I only use "manually". So I guess it is not such a big deal.

Comment: I solved the double problems differently. The original images have a 001 or 002 on other position. That indicates if it is another image for the same ID. So I just took this to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code and amend the filename to whatever you wish.

I use `round(microtime(true))` for a unique name as opposed to a DB id.

```
$temp = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$filename = "filename"
$newfilename =$filename . '.' . end($temp);
move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_dir . $newfilename);
```

Don't forget to check if your file has been uploaded.

Comment: I think you may need to read the question again a little closer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats a start and basically all I was loooking for. I will try it and post my result in case it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$files = glob($dir.'/*'); //get all images
$i=1234;
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file)){
            copy($file,'folder/'.$i'.jpg');//copy ABC_1234-sometext.jpg to 1234.jpg
            unlink($file); //delete ABC_1234-sometext.jpg
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query to fetch images clumn and change image names with new random names without changing extention.
Or load them on a page then rename all with new name and update table.
to get first part of images use :

```
$file_name = $row['img'];
$image = explode('.',$file_name);
```

use This to change names `$image`
and then include their extentions

```
$chagedImage =$image . '.' . end($temp);
```

Use this value in your move_upload `$chagedImage`

```
UPDATE :
```

I think runing this query will do the job

```
function generatenewstring($lenght){
//This function creates random tokens for new name
        $token = 'qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM0123456789';
        $token = str_shuffle($token);
        $token = substr($token, 0, 36);
        return $token;
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM your_table');
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $id = $row['id'];

    $image = explode('.',$row['img']);
    $extension = pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
//$image this is your old image name

    $chagedImage = generatenewstring(20) . '.' . $extension);

//$chagedImage this is your new image name

    $sql = "UPDATE your_table SET image = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$chagedImage, $id]);
```